Is there a frequency pair appropriate for a temporary mobile 70cm repeater?
I am thinking about building a portable low power 70cm repeater for field and emergency operations.  For example it could be placed up high on a mountain to cover the valley.
Is there an appropriate frequency pair for this kind of use?  I was thinking of using the standard 5 MHz split and tone CTCSS.  Nothing fancy.
The idea is to have something that could be easily carried in a backpack with its own battery that would run it a full day, and a tripod mounted antenna.

Likely this is a question you need to ask your local frequency coordinator.  Some regions reserve pairs for this specific purpose.

So far two emails and no response after several weeks so it seems the MA UHF frequency coordinator is AWOL, hence my asking here.

Plus your local emergency communications folks (such as ARES - see the ARRL emergency coordinator, and your local search and rescue folks too) should be in on it should you want it to be useful to them.

Likely this is a question you need to ask your local frequency coordinator. Some regions reserve pairs for this specific purpose.   Check your region's frequency coordinator's website and see if they list this service or list roaming pairs.
If you get no response from the frequency coordinator, and they don't list anything relevant on their website or bylaws, then you will need to pick your own pair.
First, you should be aware of what repeaters are near by at your destination and any repeaters that are just barely out of range and adjacent frequencies to those pairs, and avoid all those pairs.  Have ready a list of potential free pairs.
Pick a pair, and sit on it for at least an hour, listening to both input and output, and if you hear any activity, choose a different pair.  Repeaters are suppose to beacon on their output frequency at least every half hour.  Repeaters with clocks usually will do this on the hour and half hour (but clock drift might affect this so don't rely on exact timing).  During this waiting time, you should also try to put out a CQ on both the input and output frequencies, both with and without the region's likely local CTCSS tones, and see if you get a response, either from the repeater or from a person.  If the pair doesn't seem clear, check the next pair on your list.
Once you have verified the pair is clear, you can try setting up your repeater temporarily on the pair.
In general, amateur radio does not allow an individual to reserve frequencies for a specific use.  Repeaters are an exception to this, and the frequency coordinator is suppose to assist with making the reservation.   If you get no response from a frequency coordinator and you have done your due diligence to make sure the frequency is clear and prevent any interference, you can't be penalized.  However, be ready to switch to another pair if you get a complaint over the air.
The length of time you monitor a pair for activity should be proportional to the amount of time you expect to have your repeater on the pair.
Note also that if you are in a small region or near the edge of a region, it might be a good idea to check with the frequency coordinators for near by neighboring regions too.

I just sent another email, this time to a wider range of members of the New England coordinating org.  There are itinerant and wide range frequency pairs which would likely be most appropriate and from my basic tests I think +20 dBm transmit power would do quite nicely.

People, like, go on vacation and stuff.  Contacting a single person and waiting only 2 weeks is not enough.  I would hope they'd have a committee and a common email address to hit all of them or something.  But it sounds like you've got what you need!  Have fun!
